# how to send a message in a dialog whose type is Public group with quickblox JS SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quickblox

I am using the code to send a message in publicgroup. messages are not received in a dialog.

```
let message = {
  type: "groupchat",
  body: `${this.state.inputMessage}`,
    
  extension: {
    save_to_history: 1,
    // dialog_id: this.state.dialogId,
    dialog_id:'64a3addc32eaaf003ead0263',
    senderName:this.state.fullName
  },
    markable: 1
};
  
  let dialogJid = QB.chat.helpers.getRoomJidFromDialogId('64a3addc32eaaf003ead0263');
  QB.chat.muc.join(dialogJid, (error: any, result: any) => { })
  
  QB.chat.send(dialogJid, message);
```

need code sample for sending messages in public group. dialog type is 1